# Average of part of poisson distribution

Tags: statistics

Is there a way to find the average of part of poisson distribution? I tried it by finding the center of gravity of that part. However I faced the integration of factorial in the denominator of the pmf of poisson distribution
Thanks

Comment: The Poisson distribution is discrete, it doesn't have a pdf, but instead has a pmf. Are you looking for a proof of the expected value of the Poisson distribution?

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for the expected value of part of it.

Comment: See this http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Expectation_of_Poisson_Distribution

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for the formula to find the expected value of part of it, for example, the area bounded by F_inv(90%, lamda) and infinity